# how to remove the first comma of a print statement in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to remove the first two commas of a print statement and am having trouble doing this.

The print statement essentially allows to print the elements of a set without the brackets (using *) and with commas separating the elements (using sep=", ").

Only problem is the first two pieces of the statement (a cross mark and a sentence) also get separated with a comma. This is not desired (as shown in screenshot).

I would like to know how I can remove the comma after the cross mark and the comma after the colon.

FYI: '\033[91m' = red font colour, '\u274C' = cross mark, '\033[0m' = no color

My code is shown below.

```
print('\033[91m' + '\u274C', "Paragraphs contain unspecified font(s):" + '\033[0m', *invalid_font, sep=", ")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps an f-string would better suit the first section of the printed statement, then use splat expansion for the items themselves (as you are already using).

Comment: `", ".join(invalid_font)` and remove `sep=", "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either, use two separate `print` statements.

```py
print('\033[91m\u274C '
      'Paragraphs contain unspecified font(s):'
      '\033[0m', end='')
print(*invalid_font, sep=", ")
```

or `join` the fonts with comma and space.

```py
print('\033[91m\u274C '
      'Paragraphs contain unspecified font(s):'
      '\033[0m',
      ', '.join(map(str, invalid_font)))
```

**Edit**

As @S3DEV pointed out in the comments, it is unnecessary to map the `invalid_font` iterable to `str` if it is already an iterable of `str`. In this case, you just need

```py
print('\033[91m\u274C '
      'Paragraphs contain unspecified font(s):'
      '\033[0m',
      ', '.join(invalid_font))
```

Comment: Is mapping `invalid_font` to `str` necessary? *Presumably* just `', '.join(invalid_font)` should be enough.

Comment: @S3DEV It's uncertain what the `invalid_font` iterable contains. In fact, you can see in the screenshot the iterable may contain `None`. I included the `map` just to be safe, but I will edit my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Excellent, fair play.  :-)

Comment: `join(invalid_font or []) ` would handle the None case, I believe. If it was needed - you probably only call this code when there is something.

Comment: @JLPeyret What I meant is that the could be `None` in the list, not that the variable may be `None`.